# Displaying JSON array results one per line in a table cell

Tags: javascript, c#, html, knockout.js

I have a table which displays the column "air segments". The air segments come as a JSON array from the server(see picture), I need to display the contents of the air segments column one per line in a table cell. Right now its getting displayed as a complete string with a comma(See picture below).

[image: JSON document].

So the HTML code is as follows:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $parents[0].outputsToDisplay($data) -->
    <td>
        <span data-bind="foreach: $data, visible: $parents[2].outputs()[$parent.index()].internalname ==='air_segments', text: splitAirSegments($data)"><br></span>
   </td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The outer 'for each' supplies the $data to the td, which are the results to be populated in the table.

The visible binding property makes sure that only column air_segments gets populated.

The outputs() is an observable array in the js file.

I need to code a JS method "splitAirSegments" such that it returns the air segments one by one and with help of 'br' I break the line  which would eventually make the air segments appear one per line in a single table cell.

What I tried:

```
self.splitAirSegments = function (arr) {
    return arr;
}
```

The way I understood it was, the 'for each' from the 'span' would send each of the air segment to this function and the HTML will display it with line breaks as soon as the function returns the value.

What can be the correct approach? Are there any other ways to split the air segments(with delimiter as a comma) which is now displaying all the air segments together with a comma.

[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: You could use a `ko.computed` and format the items as you'd like. Or just nest several `span`s with your data-bind to visible and text. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a fiddle. ko.computed seems to be a viable option. Would the ko.ccomputed function take $data as an argument and process over it to split the strings?

Comment: If I'm understanding you, and your data coming as JSON, then you could setup a viewModel for all your observables in the JSON object (your $data). Then in your ko.computed, you could call each one of those observables and print its value. I may be misunderstanding you too.

Comment: *The way I understood it was, the 'for each' from the 'span' would send each of the air segment to this function* : The `foreach` should be on the `td` not the `span` with the `<br/>` outside the span. I'm not sure how that is even working as you shouldn't be able to have both `foreach` and `text` on the same element without a complaint regarding *"Multiple bindings (foreach and text) are trying to control descendant bindings"*. Also, *the visible binding property makes sure that only column air_segments gets populated* isn't quite what I think you want. Try a containerless `if` binding.

Comment: How can I achieve a if internalname ==='air_segments' then do a for each on the data and then send the data to js function to split the strings. Can anyone give me the data-bind for that?

Comment: Given that the data is in an array you don't need a splitting function as the `foreach` will do that for you. I put together a [very generic example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/9m0dh4fp/) using the `if` binding. Another approach would be to use templates.

Comment: If you would want to add the above comment as an answer I would be happy to accept it. Coz the comment helped me in getting the issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

On the lines of user @Origineil's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/9m0dh4fp/) the below worked for me:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $parents[0].outputsToDisplay($data) -->
   <td>

    <span data-bind="if: $parents[1].Outputs()[$index()].InternalName === 'air_segments'">
        <span data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
            <br/>
        </span>           
     </span>

  </td>
<!-- /ko -->
```